# How To Align Links In TopNavBar Using CSS?

Tags: css, css-float

I've created a responsive fixed Top Navigation Bar for a site I'm working on. I'm teaching myself CSS and as of this moment, I only have 2 weeks experience with the language.

Fiddle Link can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2dqwcgvh/).

```
/* BASIC STYLE START */

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* BASIC STYLE END */





/* NAVIGATION BAR START */

ul.topnav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2F2E2E;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

ul.topnav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
    color: #B0AAA9;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
    color: #B0AAA9;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    ul.topnav li.right,
    ul.topnav li {
        float: none;
}
}

/* NAVIGATION BAR END */
```

My issue is with aligning the links within the Nav Bar. I want to align the below accordingly.

Allegiance Title - Left side of Nav Bar
Home-FAQ Links - Center Column of Nav Bar
Register & Login Links - Right of Nav Bar

The problem I face is that I can't seem to actually manage to align them properly. I figured out how to change the class in HTML and move the Register & Login links to the right, but I can't move the Home-FAQ links to the centre. Also, when I do change values in padding / margin in the Nav Bar, the responsive Mobile menu changes with the links all over the place (non-centered).

I would appreciate any help as I'm very new to this. Also, please let me know if I have redundant code in the stylesheet.

Ultimately, I want to create one of those 3 column parallax scrolling sites with this Nav Bar sitting on top. I was going to use a downloaded template, but there is no point as I won't learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issues are:

1. You cannot have a `<div>` directly inside `<ul>`. It's totally invalid.
2. The rule `ul.topnav li.right, ul.topnav li` is contradicting with `float: none;`

What you need to do is, create this rule:

```
ul.topnav li {float: left;}
```

You should be all set. If you need parallax scrolling, it definitely requires JavaScript.

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9go9x2ug/**

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment fully. I'm really new to this coding thing. So are you saying the first issue is with the HTML code and the second one is with the CSS code? I understand I will need JS for parallax scrolling. When I opened your Fiddle link and checked the responsive view, the nav bar is not stacked anymore.

Comment: @AndrewGaw Thanks for your comment. Can you explain the "stacking" part?

Comment: @Pravenn Kumar - Appreciate the help here. I mean, on my browser, that when I reduce the size per the original code used in my original fiddle, the nav bar stays on top but the links are stacked on top of each other. For instance, when the screen is less than I think800px the Allegiance title link is at the top with everything else below it from left to right stacked from top to bottom if that makes any sense. so Allegiance,Home, programs, etc. all on top of each other. But when I used your fiddle, the links stop stacking and stay horizontal. as opposed to vertical stacking.